# Narrow down DT using plotly_click in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-markdown, dt

Plot plotly heatmap on Rmarkdown. I want to display the DT of the clicked data by clicking the heatmap. It was possible with Shiny. Is it possible to reproduce this function with Rmarkdown? Thank you

#### rmarkdown.Rmd

````
```{r}
library(plotly); library(DT); library(shiny)
p <- plot_ly(data=iris, x=~Sepal.Length, y=~Sepal.Width, z=~Petal.Length, type="heatmap", source = "heat")
p

observeEvent(event_data("plotly_click", source = "heat"),{

x <- event_data("plotly_click", source = "heat")$x
iris_ <- filter(iris, Sepal.Length == x)

dt <- datatable(iris_)

})
dt
```
````

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way I could get it to work, but hoping you can convert this into a heatmap. For me, the heatmap wasn't rendering properly. This example uses the `crosstalk` function and utilizes brushing and will auto render the DT table of the selected table.

````
```{r}
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(DT)


m<-highlight_key(iris)
p<-ggplot(m,aes(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width))+geom_point(aes(color = Species))
gg<-highlight(ggplotly(p),"plotly_selected")
crosstalk::bscols(gg,DT::datatable(m))
```
````

Comment: Hmm...
It was regrettable. I could fit it to plotly but not narrow it down. But it might be a hint, thank you for the answer.

Comment: Also found another [example](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/752) that uses shiny, flexdashboard and plotly, but just not a heatmap, hopefully this will give you more code if you haven't already found this link. Thank you.